# Getting the hexcolor

Tags: html, css, image, hex

I am trying to get the hex color of a specific point on a random web page.  (pause)  Is there a way to do this with code or is there a site that I can figure out the hex-color?  I am stumped.

Comment: Are you looking at a manual process, or to get this programmatically?  If manual, plugins are available for browsers (eg. Color Picker) that will give you the hex (and other) color values of selected pixels using a picker tool.

Comment: Are you trying to automate it? Do you know the container of this "specific point" on a random web page?

Comment: Why not use the Google Chrome developer tools to examine the applied style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Instant Eyedropper](http://instant-eyedropper.com/).

The benefit I enjoy is if I need to get the html color code of something I like, I use the eyedropper to get the code. The one drawback is that it doesn't work real well with multiple monitors. If you want a color, you'll need to move the object to your main monitor and get the color code. There's a lot to do with the mouse as far as options go but I've been using it for almost 2 years without fail.

Comment: Please expand a little about Eyedropper. What are its benefits, and more important, its drawbacks?

Comment: The benefit I enjoy is if I need to get the html color code of something I like, I use the eyedropper to get the code. The one drawback is that it doesn't work real well with multiple monitors. If you want a color, you'll need to move the object to your main monitor and get the color code. There's a lot to do with the mouse as far as options go but I've been using it for almost 2 years without fail.

Answer (score 3):

You need an addon for your browser for example

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/colorzilla/
(Firefox)

Comment: what is this color picker you speak of?